# DataTemplateSelector and update binding manually

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I am using a DataTemplateSelector to swap input method for user based on whether he wants to enter text or pick a date value. Which means the selector switches between a TextBox and a DatePicker. Each control must use explicit way to update binding source. To sum up the user could pick a date or he could enter a text and once he is done he may click on apply button to update sources. Though only apply button updates the souce and not on focus lost.

The owner control of the DataTemplateSelector is a custom ContentControl called InputControl which is futhermore part of a UserControl.

Here is a small piece of pseudocode just to visualize things better:

```
public class InputControl : ContentControl
{
  //// this method shall be executed once user clicks on apply button
  //// inside this method the source of binding shall be updated no matter what input method used chose
  public void Update()
  {
  }
}
```

Xaml looks kinda like this:

```
<UserControl>
 <UserControl.Resources>
  <DataTemplate x:key="text">
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=., UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}"/>
  </DataTemplate>

  <DataTemplate x:key="date">
    <DatePicker DateValue="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=., UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}"/>
  </DataTemplate>


  <MyDataTemplateSelector x:key="myDataTemplateSelector"
                        TextTemplate="{StaticResource text}"
                        DateTemplate="{StaticResource date}">
  </MyDataTemplateSelector>
 </UserControl.Resources>

 <Inputcontrol Content="{Binding Path=., Mode=TwoWay}" ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource myDataTemplateSelector}" />
</UserControl>
```

The selector looks like this

```
Public class MyDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
  Public DataTemplate TextTemplate { get; set;}

  Public DataTemplate  DateTemplate { get; set;}

  Public DataTDemplate Select(.....)
  {
    ....
  }
}
```

Now the problem is how do I update the binding source from InputControl no matter what control is selected inside the template? If you read the comments above the method InputControl.Update() you will understand better what I mean with user updating source no matter what template.

If its TextBox selected the user shall be able to just call InputControl.Update() and it will update textbox binding source. If its DatePicker the user shall be able to do the same which is only to call InputControl.Update(). The source will get updated and Inputcontrol.Update() is a central point to trigger updating process no matter what control.

To sum up the method Update() is pretty central and updates the binding source no matter if its TextBox or DatePicker.

How do I do that?

Comment: Why are you using `UpdateSourceMode=Explicit`? Based on what you're describing, it sounds like you want either `UpdateSourceMode=PropertyChange` or `UpdateSourceMode=LostFocus`

Comment: hi. i have to use it. i need to have the control when to update.

Comment: Where do you need to use it from, and for what purpose? It is likely that what you are trying to do can be better done in some other way that better suits the WPF technology.

Comment: i simply need to use explicit since it shouldnt commit value on property changed and it shouldnt commit the value when user clicks anywhere else just to lose focus. the question is how to make it work by given constants such as it must me explicit binding and it should be updated manually. i know its a challenge rachel. i would like to see your solution

Comment: If you need more information about this Rachel, feel free to ask. Though I think I described my post so far so good.

Comment: I'm still unclear about what you're trying to do. It sounds like you're trying to use WPF like it's WinForms, which only makes things 10x harder. With WPF, your UI should merely provide a user-friendly UI version of the data layer, and your data layer should be responsible for things like storing unsaved changes until they're OK to save, and committing them when needed.

Comment: But that said, you could probably navigate the `VisualTree` to figure out what object is there, get it's binding, and update its source. I even have some [helpers for navigating the VisualTree](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/10/09/navigating-wpfs-visual-tree/) on my blog that would make this easy.

Comment: It is kinda like using it as WinForm. Those are my requrements. Read the question again and if you still dont know whats all about you can ask me. The InputControl.Update() is the central method for updating no matter whats inside the template. I would like to see your solution though.